# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sports'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pip, python-import

I installed pip install sports.py from command yet when I try to import sports I get the following error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sports'.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: There has been a bug in the library for a while. You could look at their [Github repo](https://github.com/evansloan/sports.py/issues). For that reason, the library is not working. They **might** have closed the library and it is probably under construction, since then. The web scraping doesn't work anymore as scorespro.com has a paid plan that makes web scraping impossible on the site.

Answer (score -2):

As you tagged python-3.x try `pip3 install sports`

Also you can try adding the module location to your sys path like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r"/your/module/path")
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately

Comment: what environment and what IDE are you using ? to solve this we probably need some more information